# Reinstalling iMovie on a mid 2009 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, imovie

I accidentally uninstalled my iMovie from my MacBook Pro mid 2009. Thing is, when I go to the app store and try to reinstall it, I can't – my system's too old.

When I try to get an old version of iMovie, they're just updates – not the core application itself.

I need any (really... any!) version of iMovie running by today because I have an urgent video edition due.

Anyone has any clue about how to reinstall the iMovie on my old MacBook?

Comment: Can you restore your system from backup?

Comment: Not on this old computer–no time machine backup.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find a version of iMovie from Apple's iMovie download site:

https://support.apple.com/downloads/imovie

Available: iMovie versions 2.x to 9.x.

Comment: Yes I've been to this page; I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but no matter what I download from there, it says I don't have the base application. I'm thinking they're all updates – they need the base software installed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of macOS on your MacBook